# Laravel 5: What's the best Eloquent Relationship for this relation? Tasks can have one Topic AND one Project AND one

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism

I have three models:

Task
Project
Topic

A Task can be associated with a Project or a Topic or to both.

Is there any type of eloquent relationship that I can use to achieve this type of relation or do I have to use the Polymorphic Many to Many?

I don't want to use the standard belongsTo with foreign key because I might extend it to other models.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Polymorphic relations [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) defines a "type" column so your single Task could not belong to two models at once. That mean, Task can morph to Topic OR Project.
A way to solve problem you answered yourself - belongsTo, hasOne, hasMany and so on.